# error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/info

Tags: docker

System info:
Windows 10 pro 64 bit

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker --version

Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker info

error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker pull hello-world

Using default tag: latest

Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Comment: trying executing the docker run command with sudo, because the docker daemon normally needs to be run as root.

Comment: what is the command that you are running ? is it `docker run hello-world`

Comment: i uninstalled docker tool box and started with docker for windows

Answer (score 17):

You can powerShell as admin.

Run this code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Running Powershell with elevated access solved my issue.

Comment: `Unexpected token '-SwitchDaemon' in expression or statement.`

Comment: If I run it from a command prompt, without PowerShell, it just hangs.

Comment: this command just swipe from linux containers to windows containers - it not realt solve the problem. just hide it

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel I just run it and it worked for me, docker info says `OSType: linux`

Answer (score 9):

Usually this error means the Docker daemon that is docker service is not up and running.

- Make sure docker is running by issuing below command in power shell in elevated mode.

  `docker run hello-world`

  A response as hello from docker will be printed on console.
- 

Else start the docker by double clicking the docker app from start menu.
Below is the snapshot of graphically up and running docker daemon.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, go to the folder `%homepath%\.docker`, open `daemon.json` and if `debug` is set to `true` then set it to `false`.

I had the same error as in the question and after I changed the above it worked again for me. After I got the error, I had been looking at the various docker settings and decided to set `debug` to `false` because I don't need any daemon debug info for what I'm doing. I don't know why it was set to true originally.

Comment: I have made this enabled still I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same error, the following worked for me:

In the windows taskbar, the docker icon was red in color saying Out of Memory...
In the Docker Desktop App, goto

`Settings -> Resources -> Disk Image Size -> decrease the space allocated -> Apply & Restart`

Comment: For me, I had to drop the Disk Swap down. I had it at 4GB, the max and when I slid it down to 3GB suddenly `docker run hello-world` and my project worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, although I had the docker service running as admin and the service was shown as running, it was not.

Open the docker desktop app, click on the 'troubleshoot' icon. Check if the service is effectively running (bottom left). If it's not, try to 'clean/purge data', and then restart the service. It worked for me!

[image]

Verify it by running docker `run hello-world`

Comment: asking for deleting container I don't think that's a good thing to do.

Comment: Worked for me. I am on Windows and had to clear my wsl data. I did not clear HyperV or images

Answer (score 1):

Fow Windows:

Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon

Comment: How does this add to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879198/4575793)?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of organisation network certificates which are installed in local machine. Beacuse some companies restricted network by installing certificates.

Comment: Any resolution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

docker daemon service is not running on my machine and when I start the service, this error us resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Open docker with `docker <homepath>`. Simply upgrade docker and then run this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

you will be able to solve the specified path error.

> docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
> [14620] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Doing the above solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

This did happen to me while i was using docker today for the first time. I fixed by opening up the docker app in the PC and signing and selecting the necessary subscription plan.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem. To solve it, you just open Docker Dekstop and let it run normally. Then you run again your command
PS: I think you shouldn't use Command Prompt as Administrator. You should use normal Command Prompt direct to your D: or G: (as long as it isn't C:) and run your command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Docker Desktop with admin privileges.
In the settings check the option: "Start Docker Desktop when you log in"
Keep the desktop app open during use

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Yo,

open docker app > settings > Docker engine >   "debug": true,

debug was false initially, after changing it to "true" it worked.

Thanks.